# Where should an NFC timeout be handled?

Tags: android, nfc, emv

I need to return to a server a specific return code in the case of a NFC timeout in an android application.

I have found the documentation for the setting a timeout, however I cant find documentation about how this timeout should/can be handled if it occurs.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep#getTimeout()

Where should the timeout itself be handled , is it an exception or is there a method that should be overridden?

```
private boolean ConnectToTag(@NonNull IsoDep isoDep) {

    if (!isoDep.isConnected()) {

        try {

            isoDep.connect();
            isoDep.setTimeout(5000);

        }  catch (Exception e) {

            HyperLog.e(TAG, "Could not connect to tag", e);
            onNFCException(SIM.TRANSMISSION_ERROR);
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
```

}

```
@Nullable
public byte[] Transceive(byte[] apdu) {


    try {
        if (!isoDep.isConnected()) {
            boolean connected = ConnectToTag(isoDep);
        }
        if (isoDep.isConnected()) {

            byte[] response;
            HyperLog.i(TAG, "NFC => " + ByteUtils.BytesToHexString(apdu));
           
            response = isoDep.transceive(apdu);
           

            if (response == null) {
                HyperLog.i(TAG, "NFC <= null");
            } else {
                HyperLog.i(TAG, "NFC <= " + ByteUtils.BytesToHexString(response));
                return response;
            }

        } else {
            HyperLog.e(TAG, "Transceive() - Tag disconnected.");
        }

    } catch (TagLostException e) {
        HyperLog.e(TAG, "Transceive() - Error transceiving data", e);
        onNFCException(SIM.TRANSMISSION_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`response = isoDep.transceive(apdu);`

can also throw an `IOException`

so your try/catch should also handle this Exception as this is how a timeout is likely to be returned.